# Azure SQL query takes SOMETIMES too long

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure

In my code I am executing this query:

```
SELECT Id, PurchaserId, IsDeleted 
FROM Invoices 
WHERE ((InvoiceType = @InvoiceType AND CompanyId = @CompanyId AND PurchaserId > @PurchaserId AND 
    DATEDIFF(day, DueDate, @Date) = @DaysOverDue AND 
    PaymentStatus != @PaymentStatus1 AND 
    PaymentStatus != @PaymentStatus2 AND 
    SumForPayment > 0) AND 
((IsDeleted <> 1)))
```

The database is hosted on Azure using elastic pool with Standard: 100 eDTUs resource configuration.

This query is supposed to run once a day early at the morning.

The problem is that sometimes this run takes too long and ends with a timeout. This happens in the application at first, but I managed to isolate the problem only to this raw query, so when I afterwards run this query from Management studio, I get same result - the query runs for nearly 5 minutes. But when this run completes, next runs are instant. This happens randomly. Sometimes these long runs occours every day, sometimes every other week. It also might happen even when the query retuns no results.

Here is the execution plan:

[image]

I managed to also save these statistics which might also help

```
SQL Server parse and compile time:
CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.



SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.



SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time:
CPU time = 16 ms, elapsed time = 226415 ms.



(0 rows affected)
Table 'Invoices'. Scan count 2, logical reads 22, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
```

I thought of 2 things that might cause this:

1. Execution plan cache
2. Locks

None of them had proved to be a cause. I tried to clear cache by using `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE`. After clearing, query times were nearly identical. Investigation of locks was also leading nowhere, since there were no locks at the time of query execution.

If anything mentioned above needs more clarification, I am happy to add more materials.

Is there something I am overlooking?

Comment: More than likely this is parameter sniffing where your plan was compiled where the index seek was suitable however a subsequent execution would benefit from a scan. As your query executes infrequently you could use a *with recompile* hint to ensure an optimal execution plan. You could add the selected columns to the index making it fully covering to remove the bookmark lookup.

Comment: Check your indexes, and try to add columns to make it self sufficient(like Stu mentions in above comment). If the data rows that are returned are too many, then consider to use partitions on your Invoices table.

Comment: You probably want an index something like this `Invoices (InvoiceType, CompanyId, DueDate, PurchaserId) INCLUDE (Id, PaymentStatus, SumForPayment, IsDeleted)` also you should change `DATEDIFF(day, DueDate, @Date) = @DaysOverDue` to do a sarge-able predicate (one where it can use the index) `DueDate = DATEADD(day, -@DaysOverDue, @Date)`

Comment: The problem is that it takes only too long to build execution plan. If the plan is built everything runs smoothly after that. I analyzed index fragmentation and it seems that indexes are fragmented too much (50% and above). I will try to rebuild them and will see if that helps.

Comment: My theory now is that while building execution plan it has hard time deciding which index to use due its high fragmentation